# For Each fails to zero out array with use of index

Tags: javascript

```js
function zeroOutCharCounts(charCounts) {
  for (let i = 0; i < charCounts.length; i++) {
    charCounts[i] = 0;
  }
  // charCounts.forEach((_, i) => {
  //  charCounts[i] = 0;
  // })
}

var charCounts = [2,5,4,5];
zeroOutCharCounts(charCounts)
console.log(charCounts);
```

I consider myself pretty versed in Javascript syntax by now, however in the above function when I uncomment the commented code, and comment out the for loop, the code breaks, even though to my eye it appears it should do the same thing.  A console log after the function is run shows that when I use forEach, the first element of the array is blank while the rest are 0s, but the for loop zeros out every element.  Can someone please explain why this is?

Comment: forEach is for array and not string

Comment: You must use for loop as string do behave like array; having length attribute and character identified by index but other features of array like map, reduce and forEach are not available

Comment: @binariedMe—the OP says "*…the first element of the array*" so it seems to me that *charCounts* is an array. If it was a string, `charCounts[i] = 0` would not work (since strings are immutable).

Comment: what u r trying to do?

Comment: @RobG OP? I didn't understand

Comment: a good article to read if you want forEach for string as well : http://michd.me/blog/javascript-foreach-object-array-and-string/

Comment: What are you passing into the function?

Comment: The commented out code works for me, please post an example that doesn't (or perhaps your client doesn't support arrow functions).

Comment: @binariedMe— "OP" is "original post" or "original poster", whatever suits the context.